# How to open a text file in notepad in a C program?

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to show user a text file after an operation completed in a c program using winapi but I want the file to be opened using notepad (or the default text processor application). how do I do this (opening a text file using window's default application) using winapi?

Comment: You mean on the command window ? Make yourself clear

Comment: You mean [ShellExecuteEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ShellExecute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx) is what you are looking for, eg:

```
#include <shellapi.h>

ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, "C:\\path\\to\\myfile.txt", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: Don't forget to initialize COM before calling.

Comment: I like this dialog best.

Answer (score 3):

Given a file `test.txt`, you can display it in `notepad` on Windows with:

```
#include <stdlib.h>  

int main () {
    system ("notepad test.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

If you can be sure that your program will default to the `cmd` shell, you can just say `system ("test.txt")` and the file will open in whichever text editor is set as the default, but specifying the editor is safer because it deals with cases like the program being compiled under Cygwin, where the default shell will be `sh`, which doesn't open text files by default when you supply the filename at the command prompt.

If you can't be sure your program will always be compiled on Windows then I would favour the `ShellExecute()` solution outlined by @Remy Lebeau. A program containing `#include <shellapi.h>` and a call to `ShellExecute()` will fail to compile on a non-Windows system (thereby pre-empting an error) whereas my solution *will* compile on a non-Windows system but will fail during runtime at the `system()` call.

Comment: What if your system does not have Notepad (mine does not) or the user has selected a different default text editor?

Comment: Simply `system ("test.txt");`

Comment: If your system doesn't have notepad, you're almost certainly not on Windows, and are therefore irrelevant to the question of "how do I do this using winapi".